# how to customize color and text in the table

Tags: color

[image: image color.]

how to code that table with colors? using xcolor?

Comment: You can use `textcolor` for the colored text (or something like `>{\color{purple}}c` if you want to color all text in a specific row) and `rowcolor` (Use `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`)  for the background color of the individual rows.

Comment: what is the name of the colors there in the tablE? @leandriis

Comment: I don't know. to find out, you can use a color picking tool of your choice to get the corresponding rgb values. You can then define your own color using there rgb values.

Comment: i try already a 3x3 table, and when I add some columns it say that "illegal pream-token (C)": c' used. how to fix that? @leandriis

Comment: Did you add the `array` package?

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | }
  \rowcolor{green}
  A & B & C \\
  \rowcolor{red}
  D & E & F \\
  G & H & I \\
  \rowcolor{blue}
  J & K & L
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

Comment: here is the code

Comment: @leandriis that is the code

Comment: The code from your previous comment compiles perfectly fine for me.

Comment: yes. but when i replace the code: \begin{tabular}{ | C | C | C | C | C | C | C | C | C | C | }
  \rowcolor{green}
  YEAR & All Students & Freshmen & \% & Dropouts & \% & Returnees & \% & Graduates & \%\\
  \rowcolor{-red!75!green}
  D & E & F & h & g & h & j & r & j & r\\
  \rowcolor{blue}
  G & H & I & h & g & h & j & r & j & r
\end{tabular} the errors appear.

Comment: @leandriis i got errors when I replace the code, why ?

Comment: Latex by default does only know a c type column as opposed to C. If you want to use a C type column, you will have to load a package that defines such a column type or you will have to define it yourself.

Comment: You should take a look at ‘colors defined by names’ in the `xcolor` documentation.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | 1 |}
  \rowcolor{green}
  YEAR & All Students & Freshmen & \% & Dropouts & \% & Returnees & \% & Graduates & \%\\
  \rowcolor{-red!75!green}
  D & E & F & h & g & h & j & r & j & r\\
  \rowcolor{blue}
  G & H & I & h & g & h & j & r & j & r
\end{tabular}
\end{document} I try also replacing C to |1| still error

Comment: `1` is no column type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the piece of LaTeX code producing your sample table.

```
    \documentclass[8pt, a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{times}

    \definecolor{PurpleFG}{rgb}{0.54,0.35,0.71}
    \definecolor{LightCyanBG}{rgb}{0.85,0.92,0.97}
    \definecolor{CyanBG}{rgb}{0.71,0.85,0.93}
    \definecolor{BlueBG}{rgb}{0,0.46,0.71}

    \begin{document}

       \footnotesize
       \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|>{\color{PurpleFG}}c|c|>{\color{PurpleFG}}c|c|>{\color{PurpleFG}}c|c|>{\color{PurpleFG}}c|}
          \hline\rowcolor{BlueBG}
          \textbf{YEAR}                & \textbf{All Students} & \textbf{Freshmen} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{Drop-Outs} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{Returnees} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{Graduates} & \textbf{\%}   \cr
          \hline\rowcolor{CyanBG}
          2016-2017                    & 5402                  & 2070              & 0.38        & 1742               & 0.32        & 41                 & 0.01        & 856                & 0.16 \cr
          \hline\rowcolor{LightCyanBG}
          2017-2018                    & 4732                  & 1580              & 0.33        & 1202               & 0.25        & 240                & 0.05        & 1048               & 0.22 \cr\hline
       \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

The key points are:

- to pick the color you like with a colorpicker and to use its rgb data to fill a `\definecolor` as in `\definecolor{PurpleFG}{rgb}{0.54,0.35,0.71}`
- to change the background color of a row you have to use `\rowcolor` from the `xcolor` package before such a line as in `\rowcolor{CyanBG}`
- to change the foreground/text color of a whole line you can use the `>` option for the column specifier as in `>{\color{PurpleFG}}c`

I HTH.